# Закрытие активной вкладки после распечатки

Tags: jquery

Есть ли способ закрытия активной вкладки в браузере после того как отправил данные на респечатку?

```
<script>
    window.print();
</script>
```

Имеется в виду, как сделать так,чтобы после нажатия кнопки "Печать", вкладка автоматически закрывалась?[image: пример]

Comment: Вкладки или всплывающего окна?

Comment: Исключительно вкладки

Comment: закрыть вкладку можно управляя браузером извне, например selenium webdriver, JS тут не поможет, насколько мне известно.

Comment: хочется понять,как можно по нажатию кнопки Печать сразу закрыть окно расспечатки. Это возможно, на многих сайтах работает. Но как сделать не знаю

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы вы могли закрыть вкладку используя JavaScript, вам нужно открыть её используя JavaScript.

Например:

На странице с кнопкой отправки на печать

```
<input value="Печатать" onclick="window.open('http://mysite.ru/print-page')" type="button">
```

На странице mysite.ru/print-page

```
<script>
 setTimeout(function(){window.print();}, 500);
 window.onfocus = function(){setTimeout(function(){window.close();}, 500);};
<script>
```

Задержка в данном случае нужна для того чтобы в таких браузерах как Chrome окно печати не закрылось раньше вызова метода печати.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня ресурсом пользуются только в Chrome (2022), поэтому адаптация для других браузеров меня не интересовала.

Долго искал решение, в итоге сделал такой костыль, но он работает в 99% случаев.

Страница для печати у меня открывается на новой странице. В самом начале стоит скрипт window.print();.

На тег  (идет в самом начале) поставил экшен onmousemove

Окно печати открывается быстрее, чем пользователь может шевельнуть мышкой по диву. После того, как окно печати закрывается, сместив курсор хотя б на 1px - страница редиректит назад.

Это работает в 99% случаев, проверено

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Закрытие страницы</title>
        <script>
            window.print();
        </script>
        <style>
        .all_page{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:absolute;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div onmousemove="close_after_print()" class="all_page">Какой-то тест для печати</div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
function close_after_print(){
    // Работать не будет, если открыто всего одно окно 
    // ("Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.")
    //window.close();
    //За место ↑ можно редиректить
    //location.href = "index.php";
    window.history.go(-1); return false; // Если на страницу перешли откуда-то
}
</script>
```